# Start another application from a Compact .Net 1.0 app

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Is there a way to start another application from within Compact .Net framework 1.0 similar to

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start
```

on the Windows side?

I need to start a CAB file for installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/CreateProcess.html

Answer (score 2):

You can P/Invoke [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885182.aspx) or [ShellExecuteEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa923541.aspx). An alternative is to use the older [Smart Device Framework](http://opennetcf.com/Default.aspx?tabid=91) (1.4) which wraps these P/Invokes with an object model to match the desktop. The former is straightforward. The latter will make your code more portable and readable for managed developers.